# Insert multiple arrays with PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am doing a program with PHP but this is the first time I need to enter many arrays in a table. In the input I must place [] but when making the query insert how should I do? What I present in the code only saves me the last value without the [], and in the console, it passes the values ​​that I need, but it only inserts the last value.

```
<form class="" action="asignar-fechas.php" method="post">
  <?php foreach ($infoGrupo2 as $iGrupo2){
  if(($iGrupo2['fechaInicio']==$fechaA['numero_fecha'])){
      ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="id_grupo2[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo2['id_grupo'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="modo2[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo2['modo'];?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="fecha2[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo2['fechaInicio'];?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="participante[]" value="<?php echo $iGrupo['participante'];?>">
          <input type="hidden" name="jugador<?php echo $juga;?>[]" value="<?php echo $in2['id_users'];?>">
}}?>
<input type="submit" name="enviar" value="ASIGNAR FECHAS">
```

asignar-fechas.php

```
   $id_grupo = $_POST['id_grupo2'];
  $modo = $_POST['modo2'];
  $fecha = $_POST['fecha2'];
  $participante = $_POST['participante'];
  $j1 = $_POST['jugador1'];
  $j2 = $_POST['jugador2'];
  $j3 = $_POST['jugador3'];
  $j4 = $_POST['jugador4'];

$insertarF = "INSERT INTO fechaxgrupo (grupo, fecha,estado) VALUES (:grupo, :fecha,0)";
$insertF = $conn->prepare($insertarF);
$insertF->bindParam(':grupo', $id_grupo);
$insertF->bindParam(':fecha', $fechaa);
$insertF->execute();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$_POST` variables elements will be arrays, you can loop over them. You need to bind to the iteration variables, not the arrays.

```
$insertarF = "INSERT INTO fechaxgrupo (grupo, fecha,estado) VALUES (:grupo, :fecha,0)";
$insertF = $conn->prepare($insertarF);
$insertF->bindParam(':grupo', $id_grupo);
$insertF->bindParam(':fecha', $fecha);
foreach ($_POST['id_grupo2'] AS $i => $id_grupo) {
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha2'][$i];
    $insertF->execute();
}
```